# Jenkins Bitbucket Build Status Notifier Plugin not showing

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket, jenkins-plugins, bcbsn

I have a problem where the build status from my jenkins server is not showing in Bitbucket. I have followed every step here: [Bitbucket Cloud Build Status Notifier Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+Cloud+Build+Status+Notifier+Plugin) and I have also added the Bitbucket Oauth plugin.

The system log looks like this: [image]

It seems like there is something wrong with the build data. I am not an expert and I have followed all the steps as I should, what could the problem be?

Feel free the ask questions if you need more info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue after upgrade Jenkins... I don't know where is the problem, the warning message is at:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/bitbucket-build-status-notifier-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/bitbucket/scm/GitScmAdapter.java#L59

Update:

Ok I solve the issue after downgrade Git plugin to 3.9.1

Cheers

Comment: What steps did you take to downgrade the Git plugin?

Comment: In Jenkins, go to "Manage Jenkins", then "Manage Plugins", then "Installed" tab, scroll down to the "Git" plugin. I had a "Downgrade to 3.9.1" button, which when pressed, installed the older version. After restarting Jenkins, problem solved!

Comment: I just verified that the 3.10.0 version of the Git plugin also works.